# Android | How do I change ProgressBar color inside BottomSheetFragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I couldn't change `ProgressBar` color inside of `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and started testing it with `BottomSheetDialog` (not Fragment), and this is what happend:

1. Color of `ProgresBar` stays default **without** using `viewBinding` for dialogs content view:

   `bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet_search)`
2. Color is succesfully changed to required using `viewBinding`:

   `val bottomSheetSearchBinding = BottomSheetSearchBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetSearchBinding.root)`

[image]

But with `BottomSheetDialogFragment` color doesn't changes even with `viewBinding`, it always stays default.

[image]

Before that Ii simply changed `colorAccent` color in `styles` and `ProgressBar` color was changing everywhere fine, but now I have some issues with that. I also tried to set style to that `ProgressBar`, but that didn't help either. For other views required color inside of `BottomSheetDialogFragment` works fine.

Am I doing something wrong or there are some other ways to change the color of `Progressbar`?

Comment: android:indeterminateTint="@android: color/white" works only on API >=21

Answer (score 0):

`android:indeterminateTint="color"` solved the problem

Comment: this is just a duplicate ...